# Looking for non-trivial examples of solutions to 3D wave equations?

Tags: computational-physics, numerical-modelling, wave-propagation, publications

We have developed a (new) numerical scheme to solve the classical wave equation in 3 dimensions and we aim to publish the results.

We can read in the aim and scope of the journal of computational and applied mathematics :

" ...The computational efficiency (e.g. the convergence, stability, accuracy, ...) should be proved and illustrated by nontrivial numerical examples"

Immediately we can raise the question : What are known (or classical) nontrivial examples of exact solutions of the 3D wave equation? by that I mean the Cauchy problem :
$$u_{tt}=c^2\Delta u,\quad u(X,0)= f(X),\quad u_t(X,0)= g(X)$$
Nontrivial examples against which we can compare the results of the numerical scheme, that is, we need given $f$ and $g$, along with a 'computable' formula for $u(X,t)= u(x,y,z,t)$

Comment: With boundary conditions at infinity, it is hard to imagine anything nontrivial there. But if you make a delta-source initially and put a reflective box around it, then the wave will go through multiple reflections and that would be interesting.

Comment: No, we don't need boundary conditions here, the problem is well posed as it is, and has a unique solution, provided that $f$ and $g$ are both compactly supported. The wave will propagate 'freely' to infinity.

Comment: You can make non-trivial solutions through the Method of Manufactured Solutions. For your concrete case, I would assume that scattering of a wave from a sphere or any other object counts as non-trivial. Indeed, any scattering problem will do -- the instructions do not say that you must have an exact solution of the problem you're solving numerically.

Comment: @NotaChoice I understand that the problem is well posed with BC  at infinity; but I am just saying that to get an interesting, non-trivial solution, well suited for demonstration of the method, one needs some other boundary conditions, and for that purpose I propose using reflective walls around the initial perturbation seed. With those reflective walls you could for example consider how many times the  wave bounces off the walls before it dies out, so that would be a measure of numerical dissipation in your  method vs. some standard reference method.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, you want a problem without boundary conditions.  That implies that you are left only with one problem: propagation of bulk waves. If you can have boundary condition, then a scattering problem as suggested before could do the trick. The [diffraction by a hole/rigid inclusion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/556739/53167) has analytical solution.

Comment: Why not just use periodic boundary conditions on a finite domain? This will quickly lead to waves superposing and creating fancy patterns, which may be what you are looking for...

Comment: you could ad an infinite plane to your domain with different speed c. Then you could verify correctness via analytic expressions for reflection/transmission angles (i.e. snellius law).

Comment: I conclude that there is no example which doesn't require scattering or diffraction ?

Comment: If I have a numerical scheme which simulates those 'bulk waves' without any boundary condition, and that can run on any initial conditions. Of course along with the proof that the scheme works accurately, will that be enough to publish it ? 
The scheme can of course be used to simulate such reflections and diffractions, since it deals with the general case of propagation.